# Merge a line with top line using specific character in notepad++

Tags: merge, notepad++

I have text file with the below structure. I want to merge each line started with "::" with its top line.

How to merge the lines?

my textfile structure is as below:

```
x
::{abc}
y
::{def}
```

the ideal result is:

```
 x::{abc}
 y::{def}
```

Comment: Match `\R(::)` and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=::)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(?=::)          # positive lookahead, make sure we have :: after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]